# Uploading and reading a CSV file with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently in the process of making a program to upload and read csv files. I'm throwing a key error when submitting a file to be uploaded and can't really seem to figure out why and was hoping for some help. It uploaded and saved the file before I tried adding the read file functionality but after that, it started having issues. The error is saying that 'filename' is a key error even though it seemed to work fine before I tried reading the file. Help or leading me down the right path would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Views.py

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect
from app import app
import os
import csv


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.files:
            uploaded_file = request.files['filename'] # This line uses the same variable and worked fine
            uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['FILE_UPLOADS'], uploaded_file.filename))
            f = request.form['filename'] # This is the line throwing the error
            with open(f) as file:
                csv_file = csv.reader(file)
                for row in csv_file:
                    data.append(row)
            return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)


@app.route('/help')
def help():
    return render_template('help.html')

app.config['FILE_UPLOADS'] = "C:\\Users\\Zachary\\Documents\\VSCode_Projects\\monday_webapp\\app\\static\\file\\uploads"
```

Index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 style='text-align: center'>Zach's Web Application</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="lead">Upload a csv file to view its data.</p>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
        <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename" accept=".csv">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    {{ data }}
</div>
<div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: well, to start with, `request.files` and `request.form` are not the same. why don't you throw a `print(request.form)` in there before the error and see what it looks like

Comment: Printing before the error gives "ImmutableMultiDict"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In flask **request.form["input_name"]** is used to get the input data, but not for input `type=files` which are accesible through **request.files["input_name"]**, always using `enctype=multipart/form-data` in the form. You can get more info in the oficial documentation:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

On the other hand, **request.files['filename']** is a FileStorage type, the function `open(f)` expects *str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage*.

The following code should works:

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect
from app import app
import os
import csv


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.files:
            uploaded_file = request.files['filename'] # This line uses the same variable and worked fine
            filepath = os.path.join(app.config['FILE_UPLOADS'], uploaded_file.filename)
            uploaded_file.save(filepath)
            with open(filepath) as file:
                csv_file = csv.reader(file)
                for row in csv_file:
                    data.append(row)
            return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)


@app.route('/help')
def help():
    return render_template('help.html')

app.config['FILE_UPLOADS'] = "C:\\Users\\Zachary\\Documents\\VSCode_Projects\\monday_webapp\\app\\static\\file\\uploads"
```

Comment: That makes sense thanks, running it now doesn't throw any errors however the file contents aren't displayed still. It shows the data list empty before and after submitting the file

Comment: Printing row displays the file information properly but it doesn't add it to the web page

Comment: This is another issue... You're not sendind "data" to the web page because after the POST request you're "return redirect(request.url)"
If you remove that line it works correctly with "return render_template('index.html', data=data)"